# How to compare variable dynamically inside awk in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I want to dynamically compare the value of two variable and write the answer to a file:

```
#!bin/bash
Timestamp2="19:16:35"

cat find_thread |awk -F'.' '{print $1}'|awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {if ( $i == $(Timestamp2)  ) {print (i-1)}}}'>ThreadID
```

where `find_thread` file has the following content:

```
8361 19:16:35.493540
8361 19:16:35.493594
8360 19:16:41.242314
8360 19:16:41.242343
8278 19:16:39.179931
8278 19:16:39.179973
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here you go:

```
awk -v ts="$Timestamp2" '$2 ~ "^" ts {print $1}' find_thread > ThreadID
```

Explanation:

- Put `$Timestamp2` in the variable `ts` using the `-v` flag.
- Filter by the pattern: `$2 ~ "^" ts` = the 2nd column (for example `19:16:35.493540`) should start with `ts`
- Print the 1st column of matched lines

Here's another variation of the same thing:

```
awk -F'[ .]' -v ts="$Timestamp2" '$2 == ts {print $1}' find_thread > ThreadID
```

Comment: you don't want `cat find_thread | awk ... > ThreadID`, you always want `awk ... find_thread > ThreadID`

Comment: @PaulEvans Partly I assumed she will probably use it in a pipeline of `ps`, and partly I was lazy... But you're right, I fixed it now.

Comment: Nicely worded question and a very good answer with explanation. +1 to both of you :)

Comment: You're welcome. You don't see perfect answers a lot :-).